# Crosswalk plugin and PhonegapBuild

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, crosswalk

I'm using PhonegapBuild for generating hybrid-mobile-app binaries which they are making use of Crosswalk webview.

For Android apps, if you're using Crosswalk, it's necessary to generate both, x86 and armv7 binaries.

When I use PhonegapBuild service for generating binaries, it doesn't generates both of them, it's generating armv7 by default. I have to re-submit the package with different config files specifying different plugin for enforce PhonegapBuild to generate the corresponding binary.

I was wondering if anybody has been able to handle this situation without the needed of re-submitting the files with different config files.

I leave [this link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/-cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-still-not-work-with-pgb-gradle) and [this link](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/455) as a references of the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bormansquirrel,
an appropriate place to start on this is the Cordova Plugin Respository. In one of the [links you pointed to](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/455), several solutions are available for both arm and x86 platforms.

Besides the regular [crosswalk plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/3347)(arm), *wildabeast* points to [crosswalk x86 plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/4652).

If you want the plugin to come from the [Cordova Plugin Respository](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/), then you search for [crosswalk](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=crosswalk).

If you do the search, you will find two (2) plugins from *whitecolor*, which was mentioned this in the [link you pointed to](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/455).

Those crosswalk plugins are

- arm [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt-arm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt-arm)
- x86 [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt-x86](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt-x86)

To deal with not having two separate builds *Phonegap Build* now supports the `<platform (...)>` element in the `config.xml`

You can [read the blog](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build/) and the documentation for details.

- [config.xml gets an update](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/17/config_xml_update/)
- [config.xml gets an update - part 2](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/19/config_xml_changes_part_two/)

I have not tested it yet, but you should be able to place plugins in the new support paramters for `<platform (...)>`. However, if you follow the documentation to the letter (which is never correct), this should not work.

Let me know how it works.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response, the links you've shared are pointing to updated Crosswalk repos, although the problem I'm having is that when you submit an application with any of the plugins we've pointed here, PhonegapBuild always generates only one binary at a time, instead of generating the two bins x86, armv7 needed for Android when you build a Crowsswalk based app. I don't think the problem can be solved with the _new platform tags_ because both binaries are for the same platform. You could generate ios binary on the same build without Crosswalk plugin with these new tags, though.

Comment: @bormansquirrel, Your post says nothing about iOS. This is an important aspect. Crosswalk, as you know, is only available for Android, and possibly windows. There is someone working on an iOS version, but you did NOT say a word about iOS. The issue I \*think* you are talking about is building two APKs for one platform - Android. *Phonegap Build* cannot do this; And *Phonegap CLI* requires some special scripts to do. ALMOST all workflow tools produce one product - the newer tools (ANT, GRUNT, NPM, etc.) can produce more than one. Best of Luck.

Comment: Sorry for not getting to you sooner and for not expressing my question properly; Yes that's what I'm talking about, I was looking for some way of generating the two android binaries required when you're working with Crosswalk at one shot. Fair enough then, it's not possible to do that using _Phonegap_  _Build_ .